# Manipulating path element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am creating a hexmap chart using svg element in d3js. The chart is working fine though I need to reduce the size of the hexagons and is unable to.

As per my knowledge, it is somewhat related to the path element of HTML

This is what my path element looks like:

```
<path d="M395.1641842489362,-477.03703703081476L431.0882010021053,-456.29629628799995L467.0122177552744,-477.03703703081476L467.0122177552744,
-518.5185185164444L431.0882010021053,-539.2592592592592L395.1641842489362,-518.5185185164444Z" class="border" fill="rgb(240, 75, 35)" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3"></path>
```

Please let me know if you have any idea around it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the whole picture but every element can be `transform`ed. For example if you want to scale down your path, just add the property `transform="scale(0.75)"` to your tag. The number is a multiplier, so 0.75 means 25% smaller. 0.5 would mean half the size.